# How to remove specific "][" in linux

Tags: regex, awk, sed, find

I have text files with lots of brackets as below:

```
Name:[Sara,Jane,John]
FamilyName: [Alexandr,Walter,Waze]
Number: [21][44]
```

I want to just remove ][ in Number and make the file look like as below:

```
Name:[Sara,Jane,John]
FamilyName: [Alexandr,Walter,Waze]
Number: [2144]
```

Below Code remove all brackets and cant work properly, I really if any can help me in modifying this code?

```
find . -name "*.txt" |xargs sed -i.bak -e 's/[][]//g;' '{}'
```

Best Regards,
Sara

Comment: On SO we encourage users to do add their efforts in form of code so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown examples only.

```
awk '/Number/{gsub(/]\[/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** `/Number/` is looking for string `Number` in current line and if found; then using `gsub` globally substituting `][` with NULL. `1` will print current line.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ sed '/Number/ s/]\[//' ip.txt 
Name:[Sara,Jane,John]
FamilyName: [Alexandr,Walter,Waze]
Number: [2144]
```

- `/Number/` match lines containing `Number`

  - for such line, `s/]\[//` will remove first occurrence of `][`
  - `[` needs to be escaped to match it literally

`[][]` will match `]` or `[` character once. Use of `g` flag will then remove all square brackets. In this example, you shouldn't use character class because you want to match `]` and `[` in that particular order.

To give another example, to delete `foo`, you need to use `s/foo//` and not `s/[foo]//`.